# How can I delete a photo off my camera roll, but keep it in my album?

Tags: photos, iphone

I'm hitting the hide button, but it's still showing up in my camera roll. I want to delete some photos from my camera roll, but keep them in my album.

Answer (score 1):

My workflow for this - not using iCloud - is:

1. import the photos into an app (I use Lightroom)
2. label photos I want to end up on my iPhone with "for-iphone"
3. export photos labelled "for-iphone" to a folder of your choice (I use "Pictures/for-iphone")
4. in iTunes turn on "Sync Photos" for your iPhone 
   [note: find "Sync Photos" by plugging in your iPhone, opening iTunes, clicking on the little phone icon to the right of the "Music" dropdown, then clicking Photos in the list below]
5. at "Copy photos from:" pick "Choose folder..." and navigate to the "Pictures/for-iphone" folder or your equivalent
6. Hit Done

Your photos will be uploaded to your phone independent of the Camera Roll.

Each time you sync any newly-added photos in the for-iphone folder will be added to your phone.

Answer (score 0):

When you select hide option of a specific image or set of images, then it's only hidden from moments, collections and years. But still visible in Albums and camera roll. In iOS any update came so far cannot completely hide images. If you want, you have to install a third party application to hide them.

**Note**

That third party app is not connected with iOS photos. You just have to transfer your images on iOS photos to third party app and delete them from the iOS photos app.

Answer (score 0):

I’m still trying to figure this out except what  I’m trying to do is arrange my videos in a certain order while also keeping them hidden from the main album. I can’t add them to other albums because I have them hidden and if I try to move them to other albums, they will automatically get taken out of the hidden album and will show up back in my main album. I can’t find a third-party app or a way to do this at all it’s really frustrating!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/321409)

Answer (score -1):

You could upgrade your iPhone to iOS 8 (which you should do anyway for security reasons). It doesn't have a Camera Roll, so your photo definitely won't be in it.

Comment: The Camera Roll was renamed "All Photos" in iOS 8. It is the same collection, as far as I am aware.

Comment: Sure, but the photo won't be in the Camera Roll, which is what the question asked for. And the new name for it in fact answers the question, since it should be pretty clear that if a photo is removed from "All Photos" then it's been completely deleted.

Comment: It's not a helpful answer, though. @Mel was clearly asking to remove photos from the collection — whether named Camera Roll or All Photos — and keep them in an album.